# функция запускаемая при каждом клике, как реализовать?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Появилась идея сделать статус онлайна, но для корректной работы надо обновлять его при  каждом клике, а не запросе. Так как `ajax` обновляет блоки через тот самый центральный файл.

Можете привести пример `js` который бы запускался при клике левой кнопки мыши или прокрутке страницы (на ваш выбор)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или вот еще:

```js
window.onclick = function() {
  alert('test');
}
```